# How to create ajax request in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just want to send requests and get responses using AngularJs, but I haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: Take a look https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`$http`-service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) is what you are looking for. It comes with preconfigured `get` and `post` methods to make easy requests, but you can also configure your requests as you wish.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I have searched for $http-request and i got that i want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $http service or restangular for that. https://github.com/mgonto/restangular